# In what year(s) are the events of the Spike Jonze film "Her" taking place?

Tags: her

I greatly enjoyed the story and the idea that computers would gain awareness but eventually get bored of us, however I can't recall any specific hints about when the story is meant to have taken place. Any ideas?

Comment: [Spike](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BavRrRNvz8g) [Jones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spike_Jones) did not make any sci-fi movies as far as I know. Perhaps you're thinking of somebody else with a similar name.

Comment: Absolutely correct, I meant Spike Jonze :P

Comment: Sooner than you think..definitely before a Mars Landing in 2035. Hope I live to see the day when our computers decide the eventual demise of us dysfunctional humans.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as the precise year is concerned, there's no canon mention, nor has Spike Jonze mentioned a specific year in his [interviews](https://danspapers.com/2013/10/hiff-review-spike-jonze-her/) other than describing the film as "***timeless***" and set "***in the near future***".

The [script](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Her.html) describes the setting as;

> "**Slightly in the future**, the city’s been developed even more with
>   massive office, apartment and mall complexes. It’s a city designed for
>   comfort and ease."

and for the record, there are no dates listed on any of the *numerous* computer screens seen at the main character's home, office or in the train station, nor does anyone say a year during the dialogue.

The only slight clue is a series of pictures on one of the computer screens entitled "Happy 50th anniversary". The first picture seems to be of an image quality (and with clothing) consistent with the mid 1970s which would indicate that the film is set no later than about 2025.

[image: 50th anniversary pictures]

Comment: I love this site so much for answers like these :)

Comment: But aren't those photos of the same real-life couple? Based on the difference in ages that would suggest the first photo is probably in the 60s or 50s, the clothing styles look more consistent with that than the 1970s, and I don't really see anything about the "image quality" that suggests the mid 1970s.

Comment: @Hypnosifl - I was basing it on the yellowing tinge in the photo (suggesting a slight sepia-ing). Also, most family photos from the 1950s (and 1960s) were in black and white. Also, if they were from the 1950s or 1960s, their 50th anniversary would be in the past where the director has clearly stated that the film is based "in the future">